# How to declare which member of a data structure a class operates on at construction

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list

Q: Is there a way to choose in the constructor of operatorClass which member object from the container it operates on? (iter->b instead of iter->a)

More detail:

I think I've simplified this as much as I can, but we'll see what the crowd thinks.  I have an abstract template class for an algorithm I use a dozen times.  Within implementations of the algorithm, specific details of the math differ but the overall process is the same.  There are a few implemented pairs where the math is identical except for the names of the member objects in the data structure passed to the algorithm.

In my example here, I'd like to be able to define in the constructor of operatorClass which member of myContainer the function operates on.

Is there another level of abstraction I can add to define this behavior?

The goal is to not have to duplicate the math done in `myoperation`, with only a find-and-replace to change _a to _b.

The asterisks in main() and the subsequent commented out `_b` code show the implementation I'm aiming for.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

struct myContainer
{

  double a, b, c;

  // Constructor
  myContainer(double ia, double ib, double ic) {
    a = ia;
    b = ib;
    c = ic;
  };

};


class operatorClass
{

  public: 

    operatorClass() {
      // How to on implementation of class, tell the function
      // operate_on_list_of_containers() which parameter to operate on?
    };

    double myoperation(const std::list<myContainer> *mylist) {
      std::list<myContainer>::const_iterator iter = mylist.begin();
      std::list<myContainer>::const_iterator end = mylist.end();

      double sum_of_squares = 0;
      while ( iter != end ) {
        sum_of_squares += (iter->a * iter->a);
        iter++;
      }

      return sum_of_squares;

    };

};



int main() {

  std::cout  << "Hello world" << std::endl;

  // Create a linked list of myContainer objects
  myContainer mc1(2.1, 3.4, 7.2);
  myContainer mc2(0.7, 2.9, 3.1);
  myContainer mc3(5.2, 6.3, 0.83);

  std::list<myContainer> mylist;

  mylist.push_back(mc1);
  mylist.push_back(mc2);
  mylist.push_back(mc3);

  // Create object for the algorithm
  operatorClass myalgorithm_a;
  // operatorClass myalgorithm_b; // ******
  double ssq_a = 0;
  //double ssq_b = 0;

  ssq_a = myalgorithm_a.myoperation(&mylist);
  //ssq_b = myalgorithm_b.myoperation(&mylist);

  std::cout  << "The SSQ for a is " << ssq_a << std::endl;
  //std::cout  << "The SSQ for b is " << ssq_b << std::endl;

  return 0;

}
```

IRL, operatorClass is a child class/implementation of an abstract template class for the metropolis-hastings algorithm (MH). The linked list is necessary because the dimensions of the linked list are also estimated with a birth-death process (the containers are created or killed ~20-30 times per iteration of the combined algorithm).

In my problem, I have several pairs of identical MH algorithms differing only by a set of parameters (e.g. {prior_mass, mean_mass, mass} and {prior_width, mean_width, width}). My example here covers the most complicated subset of these parameters (mean, width), that are contained within the linked-list

Comment: don't pass a `std::list<>` by value (unless you want to make a deep copy and work on that). With *child class/implementation* did you mean a derived class? It doesn't have a base class though.

Comment: ::thumbs-up:: I pass by reference in my actual implementation -- I think I've changed it here correctly.

Comment: you should pass by `const` reference (or `const` pointer, but that is less idiomatic in C++)

Comment: Nit - there is no `';'` following `main() { }`

Comment: Thanks -- made both changes.

Comment: Anyone want to hint as to why the downvote?  Question unclear? Reprex insufficiently minimal?

Comment: @Walter I did mean a derived class.  In discussing that, I was attempting to provide context for what is motivating this particular conundrum.  The conundrum itself is how to vary which member variable of the myContainer objects the function myOperation() acts on --- the a, b, or c -- while still just being passed the linked list.  I removed the base class/derived class portion of the code for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect excuse to use a pointer-to-variable-member:

Change the `operatorClass` this way:

```
class operatorClass
{
private:
    double myContainer::*ptr_;

public: 

    operatorClass(double myContainer::*ptr) {
        ptr_ = ptr;
    };

    double myoperation(std::list<myContainer> *mylist) {
        std::list<myContainer>::iterator iter      = mylist->begin();
        std::list<myContainer>::const_iterator end = mylist->end();

        double sum_of_squares = 0;
        while ( iter != end ) {
            sum_of_squares += (*iter).*ptr_ * (*iter).*ptr_;
            iter++;
        }
        return sum_of_squares;

    };
};
```

And then, in `main`:

```
operatorClass myalgorithm_a(&myContainer::a);
operatorClass myalgorithm_b(&myContainer::b);
operatorClass myalgorithm_c(&myContainer::c);
```

And done!

PS: Your `myoperation()` function is written weirdly. In modern C++ it would be something like:

```
double myoperation(const std::list<myContainer> &mylist) {
    double sum_of_squares = 0;
    for (auto &x: mylist) {
        sum_of_squares += x.*ptr_ * x.*ptr_;
    }
    return sum_of_squares;
};
```

Comment: Speaking of modern C++, what's wrong with `std::accumulate()` here?

Comment: Spot on.  Also thanks for the heads up on myoperation().  C++ is not my primary language, so off-question suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: @Walter: Sure that can be done. I was merely talking about the way of doing a loop along a standard container.

Comment: @MattMulvahill: You're welcome! Talking about off-question stuff, your previous language probably used `List` as the primary container. In C++ the preferred one is usually `std::vector`, not `std::list`. The latter is a double linked list, specially useful for random insertions and splicing.

Comment: @rodrigo This is for a Bayesian/MCMC algorithm that uses a birth death process to estimate the number of and features of the myContainer objects.  So the birth-death process creates or deletes a `myContainer` object from the `List` 20-30 times per iteration of the MCMC (which runs for 250,000 iterations usually).  We know enough about C/C++ to know that double linked lists are slow, but haven't uncovered a better option (btw, the algo can be coded such that order in the list doesn't matter)

I'm a statistician writing software, not a CS doing stats, so I'm always open to suggestions.

Comment: @MattMulvahill: Well, if the order does not matter, you can delete an object from a `std::vector` by swapping it with the last one and poping that. That is worth trying if the `std::list` feels too slow.

Comment: @rodrigo  The one additional requirement is constant resizing -- the brith/death process could add 10 items in a row before one deletion occurs.  Though I guess I could allocate vectors of the max number (~60) and set to 0/not 0 instead of deleting/adding.  The whole algorithm takes ~10minutes to run, so (not-premature) optimization will be beneficial. Thanks for the suggestsions -- I'll try to report back.

Comment: @MattMulvahill You can call `vector::reserve ()` upon creation to avoid reallocating. If you cannot guess the size then `std::deque` may be a good compromise.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass in a functor, which can be a lambda, as is done with generic algorithms in the `std` library:

```
auto sum_of_squares = std::accumulate(mylist.begin(), mylist.end(), 0.0,
                  [](auto const&x, auto sum) { return sum + x.a*x.a; });
```